# how to use setMaxConnPerRoute and setMaxConnTotal with httpclient5?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, httpclient

setMaxConnPerRoute() and setMaxConnTotal() are not available with HttpClientBuilder for httpclient5
migrating httpclient 4.5 to 5.2 for spring boot 3 compatibility.
Below is the reference code:

```
BasicHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager();
cm.setConnectionConfig(connConfig);

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .disableAutomaticRetries()
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(Timeout.ofMilliseconds(30000))
        .build())
    .setConnectionManager(cm)
    .setMaxConnPerRoute(50)
    .setMaxConnTotal(200)
    .build();
```

Comment: It seems to be part of the `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder`, in other words, you need to configure a different connection manager than the one you're using right now. To be clear: this is a quick guess based on looking at the Javadoc of HttpClient 5.2.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel, yes it's part of PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder

Comment: Did you change the implementation to fix this issue?  HttpClientBuilder to PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder
cannot find symbol symbol:   method setMaxConnTotal(int)
Error:   location: class org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClientBuilder

Comment: Yes PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder can be used

Comment: @PankajNargesh do you think it would be more beneficial for others if you would provide the answer below and mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, use the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder:

```
 var connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
     .setMaxConnPerRoute(50)
     .setMaxConnTotal(200)
     .setConnectionConfig(/* add connectionConfig */)
     .build();

 var client = HttpClients.custom()
     .disableAutomaticRetries()
     .setDefaultRequestConfig(/* add requestConfig */)
     .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
     .build();
```

Comment: How do you connect the connectionManager to the client? In the OPs question, you first add a RequestConfig to the HttpClientBuilder. The PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder, which is replacing the HttpClientBuilder in your answer, does not accept a RequestConfig, it will only accept a ConnectionConfig.

Comment: @Dan you just call `.setConnectionManager(connectionManager)` on the `HttpClients.custom` builder. I somehow forgot the add it, so I updated my answer!

Comment: @Dan considering your second question, the RequestConfig is set on the client. That did not change though, check the question and answer again :P.